# Bigcommerce sitemap not accepted by Google Search Console

Tags: search-engine, sitemap, robots.txt

Bigcommerce is providing the following sitemap link:

https://example.com/xmlsitemap.php

The robots.txt file has the following entry:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /account.php
Disallow: /cart.php
Disallow: /checkout.php
Disallow: /checkout
Disallow: /finishorder.php
Disallow: /login.php
Disallow: /orderstatus.php
Disallow: /postreview.php
Disallow: /productimage.php
Disallow: /productupdates.php
Disallow: /remote.php
Disallow: /search.php
Disallow: /viewfile.php
Disallow: /wishlist.php
Disallow: /admin/
Disallow: /__socialshop/
```

I cant figure out why Google will not crawl my site. I would so much appreciate your help.

Comment: What does the search console say?

Answer (score 1):

Did you correctly registered your website on the [developer tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools)?

Google can take up to 72h for the first parsing.

I suggest you to declare your sitemap in the header of your website.

```
<link rel="sitemap" href="sitemap.xml" type="application/xml" />
```

Comment: It is registered and verified on Google Search Console

Comment: Did you also uploaded your sitemap on the developer tools?

Comment: I registered it on the Google Search Console sitemap registration. Added the sitemap url. Here is the actual URL: https://themuntu.com/xmlsitemap.php

Comment: can i refer to sitemap.xml.gz ?